# How to Get Thinkpad T480 Embedded Controller Update to Compile

Tags: updates, thinkpad

I opened Ubuntu Software for the first time in a while and saw a badge indicating an update in the 'Updates' tab.

There is an update for the Thinkpad T480 Embedded Controller (0.1.21 -> 0.1.22).

Upon clicking on the 'Update' button, I get an error message saying the update failed to compile.

[Screenshot of error message from Ubuntu Software upon clicking 'Update'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dh69y.png)

When I click on the update entry itself, I get a message saying that the "Update item in this release are applicable to Windows OS only."

[Screenshot of update entry information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiurL.png)

Why would this update show up in Ubuntu Software if I cannot install it on Ubuntu?
Is there any way I can install this update without booting into a Windows OS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The desktop application you've shared a screenshot of is the equivalent of the `fwupdmgr` CLI utility.

It looks like the vendor uploaded a broken version of the firmware but the firmware update system doesn't bother checking for update the overwrote a broken version.

Running:

```
sudo fwupdmgr refresh
```

seems to have forced a refresh of metadata for packages to download.

Running an update with:

```
sudo fwupdmgr update
```

Completed the operation successfully. After a reboot and a few minutes of waiting everything worked on my machine. I hope this helps.